# python 3.x problem with timeit '<timeit-src>'

Tags: python-3.x, timeit

timeit is not working.
I want to calculate and print the time a function need to run.
the function works well, but timeit not...
pls someone be so kind and help me out here

'''python code'''
    import timeit

```
def add_numbers(x,y):
    '''function to add together'''
    sum = x + y
    return sum

x = 5
y = 4

print("The sum is", add_numbers(x, y))

print(timeit.timeit(add_numbers))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the function name as a string and also pass the setup:

```
import timeit

def add_numbers(x, y):
    sum = x + y
    return sum

x = 5
y = 4

print("The sum is", add_numbers(x, y))

print(timeit.timeit(stmt="add_numbers", setup="from __main__ import add_numbers"))
```

You can change the `__main__` to whatever module your function is in.